# Dynamic sql for insert not working

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P1 (
    IN input TEXT
    , IN `delimiter` VARCHAR(10)
    , IN `column1` VARCHAR(10)
    , IN `value1` VARCHAR(10)
    )
BEGIN


    SET @a = column1;
    SET @b = value1;

    select @a,@b;

    SET @c = CONCAT('INSERT INTO SplitValues2(',@a,') VALUES (',@b,')');

    select @c;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @c;

    select stmt;
    EXECUTE stmt;

 END
```

Comment: What is your question, please?

Comment: What is your question and what errors are you getting?

Comment: I am getting following errors - Unknown column 'AA' in 'field list' --- CALL P1(",","value1","AA");

Answer (score 2):

You're concatenating unquoted strings into your prepared statement.  Suppose one calls `P1` as follows:

```
CALL P1('qux', 'foo', 'bar');
```

Then `@c` will contain the following string:

```
INSERT INTO SplitValues2(foo) VALUES (bar)
```

Which is probably not what you wanted, as it refers to a column named `foo` and some other identifier named `bar`.  You might consider using MySQL's [`QUOTE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) function to properly quote string values:

```
SET @c = CONCAT('INSERT INTO SplitValues2(',@a,') VALUES (',QUOTE(@b),')');
```

Or better yet parameterise the variables within your prepared statement so that they are passed upon execution:

```
SET @c = CONCAT('INSERT INTO SplitValues2(',@a,') VALUES (?)');
PREPARE stmt FROM @c;
EXECUTE stmt USING @b;
```

Note that one can neither parameterise SQL identifiers (such as column names), nor quote such identifiers using [`QUOTE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_quote).  Therefore, to avoid SQL injection attacks, one should quote and escape manually:

```
SET @c = CONCAT('INSERT INTO SplitValues2(`',REPLACE(@a,'`','``'),'` VALUES (?)');
```